# angular $apply doesn't update model property changes with webix datatable

Tags: angularjs, apply

The code below will not render any changes on each setInterval period. However, if I were to push a record using addrecord, the changes will start to populate. It appears that $apply only looks for record count changes. Is there a way to go about this? How can I re-render my model without having to add a record?

```
$scope.records = [
    { id:1, title:"The Shawshank Redemption", year:1994, votes:678790, rating:9.2, rank:1},
    { id:2, title:"The Godfather", year:1972, votes:511495, rating:9.2, rank:2},
    { id:3, title:"The Godfather: Part II", year:1974, votes:319352, rating:9.0, rank:3},
    { id:4, title:"The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year:1966, votes:213030, rating:8.9, rank:4},
    { id:5, title:"My Fair Lady", year:1964, votes:533848, rating:8.9, rank:5},
    { id:6, title:"12 Angry Men", year:1957, votes:164558, rating:8.9, rank:6}
  ];


  $scope.addRecord = function(){
    $scope.records.push({
        title:"New Record",
        rating:999,
        votes:0,
        year:2013
    });
  };

  $scope.random = function(){

    $scope.records.forEach( function(v,k){
        $scope.$apply(
            function(){ v.votes = Math.random(); }
        );
    });

  }

  setInterval( function(){
    console.log('wtf');
    $scope.random(  );
  }, 1000);
```

Update: This issue is caused by the webix library that I'm using for datatables. I'm assuming webix also has a $apply like method that need to be called after an update.

```
<body ng-controller="webixTestController">

<div>
{{records}}
</div>

<div style="width:750px;">
  <div webix-ui view="datatable" webix-data="records" autoheight="true" select="row">
    <div view="column" id="rating" sort="int" css="rating">Rating</div>
    <div view="column" id="year"   sort="int">Year</div>
    <div view="column" id="votes"  sort="int">Votes</div>
    <div view="column" id="title"  sort="string" fillspace="1">Title</div>  
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button ng-click="addRecord()">Add Row</button>
</body>
```

Comment: try to move `$scope.$apply` from random function directly into `setInterval` - `setInterval(fn() { $scope.$apply($scope.random); })`

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your setup - with markup?

Comment: let me work on one. i'm using webix so might take a while. Let me try without webix and see if that helps first.

Comment: what do you know, its an issue with webix. I'm assuming I have to call some kind of digest command for webix to refresh this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the question is wrong, what is the best practice on stackoverflow?

Comment: [Dark Knight and Pulp Fiction is missing](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?groups=top_250&sort=user_rating). :P M sorry for the side track but can't help I am a movie freak. Always a +1 when I see "The Godfather". ;-)

Comment: You can expand the context in the question explaining why it is wrong and/or make an edit/update with the right answer if you have any to help others. Add appropriate tags to question making it visible to appropriate audience. If you feel the question is not going to add any value, then you can delete it.

Comment: cool, looking through webix docs to see if there is any way to call apply()

Comment: why do you use setInterval instead of http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout? with $timeout you don't need apply

Comment: timak0: its not that i need it, i just used it. I just gave out $timeout a try and it has the same issue as $apply. This is a webix issue and not an agular one. The model outputed without using the webix directive displays the model with updated values. On the webix datatable, the view is not updated.

Comment: found it, you can call their refresh method on the datatable to get the updated model data.http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.datatable_refresh.html

Answer (score 0):

[http://docs.webix.com/api_*link*_ui.datatable_refresh.html](http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.datatable_refresh.html)

Webix requires the use of the refresh() on the datatable for the updated model to take affect.

```
$scope.records.forEach( function(v,k){
    $scope.$apply(
        function(){ v.votes = Math.random(); }
    );
});
$$("table").refresh();
```